# Combinations with repeated elements

Tags: r

I have the next problem:
I'm using the function combinations and for example de vector `x=c(1,1,3)`, but:

```
combinations(n=3,r=2,v=x,repeats.allowed=F)
Error in combinations(n = 3, r = 2, v = x, repeats.allowed = F) : 
  too few different elements
```

I want you to show this

```
   [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    2    3
```

Is there another function that works with repeated elements?

thanks

Comment: `t(combn(x,2))`

Comment: Why is there a 2 in the result?